# Graphics driver is not accepted by Windows after restart

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

My computer is very slow. After installing the graphics driver, the computer is fast and everything works fine.

After a reboot the OS (Windows 7) does not accept (or find) the graphics driver anymore.

Is this a jumper-issue? Even after installing the driver in save-mode the effect is the same.

Comment: Please open device manager and see if there are any errors - it may be disabled in here or you can try to re-update the driver.

Comment: 1) I know of almost no modern graphical cards with jumpers (exception: a few dual BIOS high end cards. But none of those should result in these problems) -- 2) I doubt the computer is slow. The screen buildup is slow. If calculate something (e.g. zip a few GB) it would be just as fast as always. (And yes, this is nitpicking). -- 3) Errors with drivers are usually logged by windows. You can check these log with the event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your OS is 64 bits and the driver is not digitally signed?
If so, press F8 when rebooting and choose the boot option that disables the enforcement of digital driver signature.

That should give you a quick check of whether that's the bit that fails, in which case you can Google for a more permanent solution such as [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-i-turn-off-digital-signature/a7047647-bf29-468f-a885-8e23d60f3daa).

Comment: You shouldn't be able to install such a driver in the first place (and Windows should warn you about it not being tested by WHQL as well). In no way it should load fine. Maybe there's some odd hardware/driver conflict on startup.

Comment: yes Mario, do you know how i can check these conflicts? In device-manager no errors apear.

Comment: Check for errors with the event viewer. (`eventvwr.msc`)

Comment: Mario, I have needed to install such drivers occasionally, the "you shouldn't" sounds a bit demagogic. The realities of the WHQL approval process are not always ideal.